# NetLogo asking turtles to hatch based on total number of turtles created during setup

Tags: netlogo

I've setup a NetLogo model to create prey animals for each patch based on the "prey-abund" value of the patch. Specifically, the number of prey created is based on a Poisson process with mean "prey-abund".  The prey-abund is derived from a ASCII file I imported to NetLogo using the GIS extension.  Now I'd like to tell individual prey to reproduce when the total number of prey is below the total at setup (or some proportion of that beginning total).  I can tell prey to reproduce when below a certain number (i.e., `numLargePrey < (18900)`), but I don't know how to tell the prey to reproduce based on the total number at setup (which changes slightly each time the model is setup due to the Poisson process). I've reproduced what I have so far.  Any suggestions on how to tackle this obstacle would be much appreciated.

```
to setup
ca
clear-all-plots
clear-output
clear-turtles
clear-drawing   
set prey-abund-dataset gis:load-dataset "data_gis/prey_total.asc"
ask patches with [ prey-abund > 0 ] [sprout-preys random-poisson (prey-abund) 
                                   [set age random 6120
                                    set size 1
                                    set color yellow
                                    set shape "cow"
                                    set status "alive"
                                    set numLargePrey (numLargePrey + 1) ]]
reset-ticks
end

to go
tick
reproducePrey
end

to reproducePrey
ask preys [ ifelse numLargePrey < (18900) 
[if hunger-prey < 60 [ if (age = 1080) or  (age = 1850) or  (age = 2555); or (age = 3285) or  (age = 4015) 
[let littersizeLarge random growthRateLarge 
repeat littersizeLarge [hatch 1 [set age 0
                                 set numLargePrey (numLargePrey + 1)]]]]
][stop]]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, all you need is to store the number of preys at setup in a global variable.

You can declare it like this at the top of your program:

```
globals [ initial-number-of-preys ]
```

Then, at the end of your `setup` procedure, put:

```
set initial-number-of-preys count preys
```

And you can later check the current number of preys against this variable, like:

```
if count preys < initial-number-of-preys
```

(or something similar)